# XPath through python

Tags: python, html, xpath

I have the following html which I have been using:

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="directions" itemprop="instructions">
<h6>Instructions</h6>
<p>Sharpen your <a href="pencil.html" class="crosslink">pencil</a> (or, alternatively, use your pen)</p>
<p>In a large paper sheet, write your name. When the ink thickens slightly, gently open the <a href="envelop.html" class="crosslink">envelop</a> and insert the <a href="letter.html" class="crosslink" >letter</a> inside folded into 3. Set aside.</p>
<p>Use the pen again to <a href="write.html" class="crosslink">write</a> your name and address into the evelope. Include the destination <a href="address.html" class="crosslink">address</a>.</p>
  <p>Seal the envelop and stamp it</p>
<p class="copyright">Instruction courtesy of John Doe</p>
</div>
</body>
  </html>
```

The result I'm expecting is getting an array of text elements ordered and without taking into account the html tags.

```
result=[
'Sharpen your pencil (or, alternatively, use your pen)',
'In a large paper sheet, write your name. When the ink thickens slightly, gently open the envelop and insert the letter inside folded into 3. Set aside',
'Use the pen again to write your name and address into the envelop. Include the destination address',
'Seal the envelop and stamp it'
]
```

I'm using python to parse the html and get the information pieces I need. with tree.xpath(''//@[itemprop="instructions"]') I'm getting the elements I need. But I can't seem to get the information in the way I want it.

My closest attempt (that still fails) is the following:

```
for a in tree.xpath('//*[@itemprop="instructions"]'):
    for i in a.xpath('./p'):
        temptext = ""
        for c in i.xpath('text()'):
            temptext += c
        for c in i.xpath('./a'):
            temptext += c.text
        tempIteration.append(temptext)
```

EDIT FOR CLARITY:

This gets me this result which is incorrect (order is wrong for the 'a' node text).
See the way pencil is at the end of element 1 instead of after 'sharpen your'. Same thing happens in the rest of the lines.

```
result=[
'Sharpen your (or, alternatively, use your pen)pencil',
'In a large paper sheet, write your name. When the ink thickens slightly, gently open the and insert the inside folded into 3. Set asideenvelopletter',
'Use the pen again to your name and address into the envelop. Include the destination writeaddress',
'Seal the envelop and stamp it',
'Instruction Courtesy of John Doe'
]
```

I haven't been able to get this working so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From my limited knowledge of python, it looks like you are looping over each <p> tag. How would it not get the last element? Can you exclude tags based on which class they have?

Comment: If I do a.xpath('./*[not(@class="copyright")]'): I can avoid getting the last element which is perfect!

Comment: Woohoo! I'm glad you sorted it out yourself.

Comment: Yeah, just missing the main problem which is how to correct the order in which the '<a>' node text is added to the result strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getchildren()` method and `text` and `tail` properties of elements.
I never used `lxml` but from the documentation [here](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html) I got it to work in the example below.

```
from lxml import etree

html='''<html>
<body>
<div class="directions" itemprop="instructions">
<h6>Instructions</h6>
<p>Sharpen your <a href="pencil.html" class="crosslink">pencil</a> (or, alternatively, use your pen)</p>
<p>In a large paper sheet, write your name. When the ink thickens slightly, gently open the <a href="envelop.html" class="crosslink">envelop</a> and insert the <a href="letter.html" class="crosslink" >letter</a> inside folded into 3. Set aside.</p>
<p>Use the pen again to <a href="write.html" class="crosslink">write</a> your name and address into the evelope. Include the destination <a href="address.html" class="crosslink">address</a>.</p>
  <p>Seal the envelop and stamp it</p>
<p class="copyright">Instruction courtesy of John Doe</p>
</div>
</body>
  </html>'''

tree=etree.HTML(html)
result=[]
for a in tree.xpath('//*[@itemprop="instructions"]'):
    for i in a.xpath('./p'):
        temptext = ""
        temptext += i.text
        for j in i.getchildren():
            temptext += j.text
            temptext += j.tail
        result.append(temptext)

print result
```

which yields

```
[
'Sharpen your pencil (or, alternatively, use your pen)', 
'In a large paper sheet, write your name. When the ink thickens slightly, gently open the envelop and insert the letter inside folded into 3. Set aside.', 
'Use the pen again to write your name and address into the evelope. Include the destination address.', 
'Seal the envelop and stamp it', 
'Instruction courtesy of John Doe'
]
```

you can then just do `result[:-1]` to throw away the last one

Comment: Awesome! I was not using the eTree function and your solution was perfect! Thanks Miguel!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, my knowledge of XPATH is limited, but could it be because you're not closing the `<div class="directions" itemprop="instructions">` element?

Shouldn't you not have this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="directions" itemprop="instructions">
        <h6>Instructions</h6>
        <p>Sharpen your <a href="pencil.html" class="crosslink">pencil</a> (or, alternatively, use your pen)</p>
        <p>In a large paper sheet, write your name. When the ink thickens slightly, gently open the <a href="envelop.html" class="crosslink">envelop</a> and insert the <a href="letter.html" class="crosslink" >letter</a> inside folded into 3. Set aside.</p>
        <p>Use the pen again to <a href="write.html" class="crosslink">write</a> your name and address into the evelope. Include the destination <a href="address.html" class="crosslink">address</a>.</p>
        <p>Seal the envelop and stamp it</p>
    </div>
    <p class="copyright">Instruction courtesy of John Doe</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I added `</div>`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You are right about the </div> but it's after the last <p class="copyright">. I updated the source html for correctness. It actually doesn't change the result I'm getting.

Comment: It seems you're getting (as far as I get XPATH, I'm not 100% sure) the inner elements of the element with html attribute "itemprop" and value "instructions", and then you're iterating through all elements with tag "p" and you're extracting all childs text and a all the text of "a" tag elements that are child. Therefore if you close the div after `<p class="copyright">Instruction courtesy of John Doe</p>` then I think you should get the `'Instruction Courtesy of John Doe'`, so in my humble opinion you're getting the expected behaviour.